# rqt_reconfigure widget

Tags: ros, rqt-reconfigure, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can the text field widget at the bottom of rqt_reconfigure window ("System message might be shown here when necessary") be interacted with? It would be very useful to display some info from the reconfigure server code callback for example

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402484/rqt_reconfigure-widget/) by [vane](https://answers.ros.org/users/54255/vane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2022-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the one who added that text area, I don't think I finished integration of it with the top pane, and I'm not aware if anyone completed it (Just skimmed through [rqt_reconfigure/issues](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_reconfigure/issues) but I haven't found anyone mentioned that text area.

I think feature change is welcomed on the repo I linked above. The text area not taking any input from anywhere should be considered as a bug, so bugfix to it should still be acceptable (new features for core pkgs in ROS1 like `rqt_reconfigure` aren't accepted as much).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2022-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0